# mongodb: Can I create an unshard Replica set for a sharded cluster?

Tags: mongodb

I have a 3 node shard cluster mongoDB with replica set, and want to add (single node replica set) a un-sharded Replica set to collect all data in one node.

Can I create an unshard Replica set for a sharded cluster?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please edit your question to clarify what you are trying to achieve? It sounds like you may be trying to back up your sharded cluster to a single node replica set. Note: questions on database administration are more on-topic for [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/mongodb). This question still needs more clarity to be answerable.

Comment: thanks  for your clarification